# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct()

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following query in my page `?filterFrom=11%2F01%2F2014&filterTo=11%2F25%2F2014`

Now I have the following code

```
// Get Start
if(isset($_GET['filterFrom']) && !empty($_GET['filterFrom'])) {
    $startDate = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '-', $_GET['filterFrom']));
    $sqlArray[":searchFrom"] = $startDate->format('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00';
}
// Get End
if(isset($_GET['filterTo']) && !empty($_GET['filterTo'])) { 
    $endDate = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '-', $_GET['filterTo']));
    $sqlArray[":searchTo"] = $endDate->format('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59';
}
```

The "Get Start" part of the script works fine, but when it gets to "Get End", I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (11-25-2014) at
>   position 0 (1): Unexpected character'

I have this exact same script on 6 other pages and don't have any issues! Does anyone know what could be going wrong??

Comment: can you show the actual $_GET['filterTo'] ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean? It's in the query up the top `filterTo=11%2F25%2F2014`

Comment: You're using `-` as a date separator instead of `/` (which itself results in ambiguous dates: `MM/dd/yyyy` vs `dd/MM/yyyy`). Use `date_parse_from_format` instead to specify the format of the input string so it's parsed unambiguously.

Comment: @Dai thanks, my script is localized to New Zealand where I am. But like I said, it's only this one line it fails on. It works the other 15 odd times it's in my site. :/ I'll give that a go

Comment: please , echo str_replace('/', '-', $_GET['filterTo'] , to see what is the actual input to the DateTime ,

Comment: @xe4me it literally gives me `11-25-2014`. Doesn't even have any whitespace

Comment: Check out this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836313/adding-two-datetime-objects-in-php

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how that applies to my issue? I'm not doing anything with time intervals. I literally just want to construct a date from a query for an SQL search.

I've ended up going with `$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['filterTo']);`

Comment: The format you are supplying to the \DateTime constructor is not a [recognised date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) in PHP.

Comment: @vascowhite but as above, it works all over my site, apart from this one line. It's so weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out php was having an issue parsing my date, so I used the following code

```
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['filterTo']);
```